# Python | Discord API BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED (Invalid Form Body)

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I'm trying to create a program that automatically responds to components that interacts with a Discord bot.

```py
def interact(guild_id, message_id, component_id):
  global channel_id, bot_id
  json = {
    'type': 3,
    'guild_id': guild_id,
    'channel_id': channel_id,
    'message_id': message_id,
    'application_id': bot_id,
    'data': {
      'component_type': 2,
      'custom_id': component_id
    }
  }
  headers = {'Authorization': os.environ['AUTH']}
  request = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions', headers=headers, json=json)
  print(request.json())
```

The code returns this error message:

> {'code': 50035, 'errors': {'session_id': {'_errors': [{'code': 'BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED', 'message': 'This field is required'}]}}, 'message': 'Invalid Form Body'}

Comment: did you ever figure this issue out?

Comment: yea, I had to include nonce and a timestamp or something

Comment: You dont need to include a nonce

Answer (score 0):

It is due a headers issue. `"content-type"` must be `'application/json'` like so:

```py
headers = {
...
    'content-type': 'application/json',
...
}
```